# Git repo with unicode chars in filename causing infinite loop of untracked files

Tags: git, github, unicode

I've got half a dozen files in my git repo, like so:

águilas.xyz
   monzón.xyz

These are causing what appears to be an infinite loop of tracked/untracked files in my repo:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    /path/águilas.xyz
    /path/monzón.xyz
```

If I do `git add .`, then they show up as "new file", which is fine. I then commit them, and doing `git status` returns "working directory clean".

Problem is with the Github app:

[image]

It now shows the files as being deleted. What's going on? I can't discard changes with these ones, but I *can* commit them. Then the cycle starts over at the beginning. Any ideas? I also can't even discard changes from the Github app. The only thing that sets these files apart is that they have unicode characters in them.

**Update:**

Renaming the files to remove the unicode chars and force pushing to remove the bad ones resolves the problem, so I'm confident it's to do with the unicode encoding.